# Joining variables with keyvariable in spss

Tags: statistics, spss, spss-modeler

I want to join two Datasets with one overlapping key variable. I just want the data of persons in dataset 1 whose ID is also mentioned in dataset one. Here is my code:

```
STAR JOIN 
  /SELECT  t0.var1, t0.var2, t1.lfdn, t1.var4, 
    t1.tester, t1.dispcode, t1.lastpage, t1.quality, t1.duration, t1.E1 
  /FROM * AS t0 
  /JOIN 'dataset2.sav' AS t1 
    ON t0.p_0001=t1.p_0001 
  /OUTFILE FILE=*.
```

When I merge them I get the variable names added to the file, but not the data in the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `match files` instead of `star join`.

your command should go approximately like this:

```
*first make sure both files are sorted by `p_0001`.
match files /file=* /tab='dataset2.sav'/by p_0001/keep var1 var2 var3.
```

Use the `keep` (or `drop`) subcommand to select the variables you need in your final dataset.